# How to rename tables in database XYZ by calling a sproc in database ABC in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to have a stored proc on database ABC which will rename the tables in database XYZ. This is what I have tried -

```
USE ABC
GO

CREATE PROC RENAME_TABLES
AS
BEGIN

USE XYZ /*This throws Msg 154 error USE cannot be used inside stored procedure*/
GO

EXEC SP_RENAME 'CASH_TRXN','MC_TRXN'
EXEC SP_RENAME 'MI_TRXN','MMI_TRXN'
EXEC SP_RENAME 'BACK_OFFICE_TRXN','MBO_TRXN'

END
```

But I get error since I cannot have `USE` inside a stored proc. Is there any alternative to it? I cannot move my stored procedure to any other db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

```
CREATE PROC RENAME_TABLES
AS
BEGIN
    execute ('USE [XYZ] EXEC SP_RENAME ''CASH_TRXN'',''MC_TRXN''')
END
```

[Source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic13446-8-1.aspx)